# How to add google-analytics in angular2 in typescript

Tags: angular, cookies, oauth, google-analytics, claims-based-identity

I am including analytics.js reference in my angular2 application. I have included the script in index.html. The problem is we are using oAuth login service and from there we are setting up a cookie and also saving in Claims, on the basis of that cookie we are deciding if we want to create cookies for google analytics or not. So I am unable to use oAuth cookie in index.html.

Is there a way to include analytics script in typescript(.ts) file?

```
    <body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
   </script>
</body>
```

I just need to add condition before the function if oAuth cookie is true only than I want to run this function. The oAuth cookie is saved in Claims which can be used in our angular application.